# Git merge Already up-to-date

Tags: git, git-merge

I made a merge between my pre and my jean branch like this:

> on branch pre

```
git merge jean
```

then I made a rollback like this:

```
git revert --hard MYHASH
```

now I'm trying to merge again with my branch jean and I getting

> Already up-to-date.

How can I merge again this branchs.

Thanks

---

UPDATE

I merged the branchs, but when I try to push to the server I'm getting this message:

To git@git.server.com:project.git
 ! [rejected]        pre -> pre (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@git.server.com:project.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: It seems that MYHASH is the hash of the merged commit. Could you confirm it once ?

Comment: No, is the hash of my commit that I made 6 days ago on my pre branch

Comment: Akshat, I made the merge, but know I'm getting the message I post in my update.

Comment: One workaround for this problem can be to pull your branch 'pre' in a fresh folder and then do the merge again.